# Mixing jQuery and Prototype while preserving $ == jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

The common solution when mixing e.g. prototype and jQuery is using `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` to restore the prototype function `$` and then using `$j` to access jQuery.

However, since prototype will be completely replaced with jQuery at some point, I'd prefer to use `$` for jQuery and e.g. `$p` for prototype. Is this possible?

I know I could wrap my jQuery code in `(function($) { /* my code */ })(jQuery);` but I guess it'd be cleaner if I could get rid of the global `$` var pointing to a prototype function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prototype doesn't have a mechanism to give up control of the $ function like jQuery does.  Your best bet, as you note, is to wrap your jQuery code in a function that has $ locally defined to jQuery.  Once you have all of the prototype code removed, you can remove the wrappers.